# Possible to use data table editor without ajax?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Currently I am using data tables populated from a JSON string. I would like to add editing functionality. Users will edit the table and then a new json string will be presented to them.

I do not want to use any sort of backend or make any ajax calls, all data will be provided by the client and never sent to the server.

Is this possible with the data table editor?

```
    var dataSet = [
['Trident','Internet Explorer 4.0','Win 95+','4','X'],
['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.0','Win 95+','5','C'],
['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.5','Win 95+','5.5','A'],];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table_view').dataTable( {
        "data": dataSet,
        "columns": [
            { "title": "Engine" },
            { "title": "Browser" },
            { "title": "Platform" },
            { "title": "Version", "class": "center" },
            { "title": "Grade", "class": "center" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

That is a sample of how I'm going to be doing this, all the data table editor examples I have seen require some sort of backend to make ajax calls to, I would like to be able to edit the table on the client side only.

Comment: What version of datatables are you using?

Comment: 1.10, but I'm not tied to any version